# What is the latex code of the braid given below using xy matrix? I have tried but the result does not look symmetric

Tags: xymatrix

[image]

I have written what I tried, in the second picture. The outcome does not look like above picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix@C=0.4cm@R = 1cm{

0\ar@/^3pc/[rrr] \ar[rrd] &&& K_{k+1}(\widetilde{W},\widetilde{M})  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] && K_{k}(\widetilde{M})  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] && K_{k}(\widetilde{W},\widetilde{M}')  \ar@/^3pc/[rrr] \ar[rd] &&& 0\\  
&& 0 \ar[ru] \ar[rd] && K_{k+1}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{\partial W}) \ar[ru] \ar[rd] && K_{k}(\widetilde{W})\ar[ru] \ar[rd] && 0 \ar[rru] &&\\
&&& 0 \ar[ru] \ar@/_2pc/[rr] && K_{k}(\widetilde{M}')\ar[ru] \ar@/_2pc/[rr] && 0 \ar[ru] &&&   

}

$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry, but this site is not a `please do this for me` service. Provide what you have so far and and a concrete question.

Comment: Please don't post a picture of code.  The actual code that you had posted was much better, it just needed to be formatted using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the cells to be as wide as 00.

The triple jump in the first and last entries was wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
% a local command to equalize all cell widths
\newcommand{\zw}[1]{\phantom{0}\makebox[0pt]{$#1$}\phantom{0}}
\xymatrix{
\zw{0}
  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{K_{k+1}(\widetilde{W},\widetilde{M})}
  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{K_{k}(\widetilde{M})}
  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{K_{k}(\widetilde{W},\widetilde{M}')}
  \ar@/^3pc/[rr] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{0}
\\  
&
\zw{0}
  \ar[ru] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{K_{k+1}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{\partial W})}
  \ar[ru] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{K_{k}(\widetilde{W})}
  \ar[ru] \ar[rd] &&
\zw{0} \ar[ru] &
\\
&&
\zw{0}
  \ar[ru] \ar@/_2pc/[rr] &&
\zw{K_{k}(\widetilde{M}')}
  \ar[ru] \ar@/_2pc/[rr] &&
\zw{0}
  \ar[ru]
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]